# How many sql audit files can function sys.fn_get_audit_file can read at once?

Tags: sql-server, audit, audit-logging

I know function `sys.fn_get_audit_file` can read multiple .sqlaudit files at once. But I could not find any information regarding maximum number of files this function can read.  Any idea about the file number limitation?

Also I need to monitor certain databases which contains sensitive information. I have three SQL Server Instances and three Databases on each. Is it okay to have all Audit Log files (3 * 3 = 9) to be placed into one common folder in network and use `sys.fn_get_audit_file` to read the logs at once. The logs are going to be really big. I intend to use this approach and write a C# console app to dump the logs into one SQL table. Any suggestion?

Comment: The limit to how many would probably be a resource (like memory) limiatation. The function itself doesn't seem to be restricted. For your second question, sure if you want but this network share would need to open access to all sql instances so you have to manage that.